# Does the synchronized keyword solve the visibility problem?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class Q2 {
    static long value;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        Runnable r = () -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
                synchronized (Q2.class) {
                    value++;    
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t1 = new Thread(r);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r);
        
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        Thread.sleep(100000); //wait enough time

        System.out.println("value = " + value);
    }
}
```

I understood that without the synchronized keyword the output would not be 200000000 due to concurrency issues.

However, since the volatile keyword is not attached, I think that the visibility problem should occur in the value value that each thread reads.

I tried that code several times, but the output is always 200000000.

Is this just coincidence or luck?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you mean by "the value value that each thread reads."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, since the volatile keyword is not attached, I think that the visibility problem should occur in the value value that each thread reads.

A `synchronized` block takes care of both memory synchronization as well as mutex locking.  It has a read memory barrier at the start and a write memory barrier at the end meaning that each thread will see the most up-to-date version of `value` when it goes to increment it and they will publish the updated value as they leave the `synchronized` block.  Both threads are synchronizing on the `Q2.class` instance so only one thread will be doing the `value++` at a time.

Couple of general comments about the code:

- You should call `t1.join(); t2.join();` instead of the sleep.  `join()` waits for the thread to end and also ensures that the main thread gets any updates made by the thread being join-ed on.  It also means that the main thread will continue immediately when the background threads finish without having to sleep some arbitrary amount of time.
- This is probably an academic exercise but just FYI you could use an `AtomicInteger` which wraps a `volatile int` field and would allow you do increment without the `synchronized` block.

Comment: Thank you. As you said, this is the code I wrote for academic practice. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, any synchronization action guarantees visibility. The spec [writes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4):

> Synchronization actions induce the synchronized-with relation on actions, defined as follows:
>
> - An unlock action on monitor m synchronizes-with all subsequent lock actions on m (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).
> - A write to a volatile variable v (§8.3.1.4) synchronizes-with all subsequent reads of v by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).
> - An action that starts a thread synchronizes-with the first action in the thread it starts.
> - The write of the default value (zero, false, or null) to each variable synchronizes-with the first action in every thread.
> - The final action in a thread T1 synchronizes-with any action in another thread T2 that detects that T1 has terminated.
>
>   T2 may accomplish this by calling T1.isAlive() or T1.join().
> - If thread T1 interrupts thread T2, the interrupt by T1 synchronizes-with any point where any other thread (including T2) determines that T2 has been interrupted (by having an InterruptedException thrown or by invoking Thread.interrupted or Thread.isInterrupted).

and goes on to say (emphasis mine):

> Two actions can be ordered by a happens-before relationship. If one action happens-before another, then the first **is visible to** and ordered before the second.
> If we have two actions x and y, we write hb(x, y) to indicate that x happens-before y.
>
> - If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y).
> - There is a happens-before edge from the end of a constructor of an object to the start of a finalizer (§12.6) for that object.
> - If an action x **synchronizes-with** a following action y, then we also have hb(x, y).
> - If hb(x, y) and hb(y, z), then hb(x, z).

Comment: thank you I learned the importance of looking up Java's official documentation. Helped me a lot.