# Visibility of HashMap elements in synchronized block

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hashmap, synchronized

I have researched many times to find out an answer for my question.
In Spring, we have this class https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/b595dc1dfad9db534ca7b9e8f46bb9926b88ab5a/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java.

And I have a question about singletonFactories field(line 81) and its usage.

1. Why this field has type of HashMap instead of for example ConcurrentHashMap? Is it thread safe?

I suppose because this field is only used within synchronized block using always the same monitor object(this.singletonObjects) and changes after exit synchronized block will be visible to others at the enter of block with the same monitor.
And my second question is: 2. Will all changes of singletonFactories(put operations) will be visible to other threads?
Will thread 2 see new value added by thread 1 some millis ago? Array in HashMap is not volatile.

Yes, we have synchronization on this.singletonObjects, but it works only for assigning a new value to singletonFactories field, isn't it? Or flushing field at the exit means that all embedded fields are also flushed into main memory? And all threads will see actual reference on singletonFactories, but I'm not sure that changes(putting new object into map) with singletonFactories will be visible after exit a synchronized block.

I suppose that is thread safe but I want to know more.

Thanks for help!!!

I expect thread safe behavior but I'm not sure that I understand it well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the synchronized keyword solve the visibility problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75714538/does-the-synchronized-keyword-solve-the-visibility-problem)

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` is not thread-safe but `singletonFactories` is only used in `synchronized`-blocks.

If we take a look at one of the methods accessing it, we can see that:

```java
//code from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/b595dc1dfad9db534ca7b9e8f46bb9926b88ab5a/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java#L137-L144
//licensed under Apache 2
//comments have been added
protected void addSingleton(String beanName, Object singletonObject) {
        synchronized (this.singletonObjects) {//synchronized here
            this.singletonObjects.put(beanName, singletonObject);
            this.singletonFactories.remove(beanName);//access inside synchronized block
            this.earlySingletonObjects.remove(beanName);
            this.registeredSingletons.add(beanName);
        }
    }
```

Since all uses to the `HashMap` are guarded using the intrinsic lock of `singletonObjects` (`synchronized`-blocks), the code is thread-safe even though it uses a `HashMap`.

It is probably done this way as `singletonFactories` is mainly used for initialization and/or rarely contended or synchronization is necessary anyways due to the objects needing to be changed together (e.g. maybe they want to avoid two methods updating it at the same time) and if there is a `synchronized` block, no `ConcurrentHashMap` is necessary.

On the other side, existing Spring beans may be read very often/from different threads so access to them could have higher contention resulting in `ConcurrentHashMap` being required.

Note that I'm not a Spring developer/I have not written this code. I am just making assumptions based on the code I'm reading.